# I am trying to make an analog clock with vue.js. Everything is working as intended except the clock-needles, which are not changing there position

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I called *intervals* after mounting, which calls *updateClock* function at a time interval of 1s. Then I set the values of hourRotate, minRotate and secRotate. But the needles are not moving.

template ->

```
<div class="hand hr" style="--wid:0.5rem; --hght:5rem; --clr:green; transform:hourRotate"></div>        <div class="hand min" style="--wid:0.4rem; --hght:8rem; --clr:purple; transform: minRotate"></div>
<div class="hand sec" style="--wid:0.2rem; --hght:12rem; --clr:pink; transform: secRotate "></div>
```

script ->

```
<script>
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: 'clock',

  mounted() {

    this.intervals();

  },

  data() {
    return {
      hourRotate: "rotateZ(0deg)",
      minRotate: "rotateZ(0deg)",
      secRotate: "rotateZ(0deg)" 
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    intervals() {
        setInterval(this.updateClock, 1000);
    },

    updateClock() {
      let now = new Date();
      let seconds = now.getSeconds()/60*360;
      let minutes = now.getMinutes()/60 * 360;
      let hours = now.getHours()/12 *360;
       console.log(minutes, seconds, hours);
      this.secRotate = `rotateZ(${seconds}deg)` ;
      this.hourRotate = `rotateZ(${hours}deg)`;
      this.minRotate = `rotateZ(${minutes}deg)`;
      

    }

  }
}
</script>
```

why are the needles not rotating ?

Comment: Your `style` attribute is just a string literal so doesn't pick up the data values.

Comment: This isn't the answer to your question, but a warning that over time, setInterval will lag, as the way it works is that it will be called no sooner than 1 second past the last call... so lag builds up over time. If you are doing a clock, it is probably better to use setTimeout and subtract the present time from the next time to get the right delay.